# Rally Question: Can I get the Parent of a Portfolio Item Feature?

Tags: javascript, rally

I'm creating a custom grid where I want to display the portfolio items that are features and also the parent of the feature (which would be the portfolio item initiative). Is there any way I can do this?

```js
var portfolioItemStore = Ext.create('Rally.data.wsapi.Store', {
            model: 'Portfolio Item', 
            autoLoad: true,
            listeners: {
                // ...
            },
            filters: [
                {
                    property: 'PortfolioItemType.Name',
                    value: 'Feature'
                }
            ],
            fetch: ['Name', 'PortfolioItemType', 'Parent'] // possible edit here
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You were on the right track. This is a basic grid to get you what you want:

```
this.add({
    xtype: 'rallygrid',
    columnCfgs: [
        'FormattedID',
        'Name',
        'Owner',
        'Parent'
    ],
    context: this.getContext(),
    enableEditing: false,
    showRowActionsColumn: false,
    storeConfig: {
        model: 'PortfolioItem/Feature'
    }
});
```

More grid examples can be found within the SDK documentation: https://rally1.rallydev.com/docs/en-us/saas/apps/2.1/doc/index.html#!/example